# Algorithm Sort function doesn't work C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, permutation

I am doing a function to compare if two vectors of strings are permutations of each other. I am trying the next code that should be working but for some reason the sort function from the algorithm library from C++ doesn't work.

```
bool esPermutacion(vector <string>  s1, vector <string>  s2){

 if (s1.size() == s2.size()){
     sort(s1.begin(), s1.end());
     sort(s2.begin(), s2.end());

    return s1 == s2;
 }

 return false;
}

int main(){

    vector <string> s1;
    string s = "";
    vector <string> s2;
    cin >> s;
    s1.push_back(s);

    cin >> s;
    s2.push_back(s);
    cout << esPermutacion(s1, s2) << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

[image: Results on my computer]

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

If i try this:

```
bool esPermutacion(vector <string>  s1, vector <string>  s2){

    if (s1.size() == s2.size()){
        sort(s1.begin(), s1.end());
        sort(s2.begin(), s2.end());

        for (int i = 0; i < s1.size(); i++){
            cout << s1[i];
        }
        cout << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < s2.size(); i++){
            cout << s2[i];
        }
        cout << endl;


        return s1 == s2;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I can see that the sort function is not working

Answer:

```
bool esPermutacion(string  s1,string s2){

    if (s1.size() == s2.size()){
        sort(s1.begin(), s1.end());
        sort(s2.begin(), s2.end());
        return s1 == s2;
    }

    return false;
}
int main(){

    string s1 = "";
    string s2 = "";
    cin >> s1;
    cin >> s2;
    cout << esPermutacion(s1, s2) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is working now. thank you all!

Comment: "compare if two strings are permutations of each other" - this code doesn't do that. This checks if two vectors of string are permutations.

Comment: I am pretty sure the `std::sort` function works.

Comment: After sorting you can just do `return s1 == s2;`.

Comment: Maybe try `std::sort()` with the `std::` at the front.

Comment: If you really think the `sort` function isn't working, then test the `sort` function to prove it.

Comment: Do you really think `std::sort` is broken? May be this can help... http://pragmatictips.com/26

Comment: Your code works for me. Therefore the broken code must be somewhere else. Maybe show us how you initialize your vectors and call the function?

Comment: You are only putting one string into each vector. Therefore the search must be working as there is nothing to sort between.

Comment: That output is correct `0 == false`. Try: `cout << std::boolalpha << esPermutacion(s1, s2) << endl;`

Comment: @AndresCavazos as @TheParamagneticCroissant said, you are sorting the strings in the vector, not the charaters in the string, just pass a `string` instead of  `vector<string>` and you're done

Comment: @Galik I just added an image with my results. It is pretty wierd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am doing a function to compare if two vectors of strings are permutations of each other

You are indeed doing this, and it works correctly.

But your example input makes it obvious that you actually want something else: you actually want to compare *if two strings are permutations of each other*, not two *vectors of strings*.

Here’s the issue: not in the code but in the specification.